# Given $a_n \to \infty$ and $a_nb_n \to 2$, then $b_n \to 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have bumped into some questions I wasn't too sure about, would appreciate your help.

it goes like this: **given $a_n \to \infty$ and $a_nb_n \to 2$, then $b_n \to 0$**

So I thought about a satisfying example $b_n = \frac{2}{n}$ $a_n \to n$, and I couldn't find a contradicting example, so I tried to proof it by formal way, but without any success.

this is what I tried:
let's assume $b_n \not\to 0$, thus either $b_n$ tends to some specific number **K** or it tends to $\pm\infty$

1.if it tends to some specific number **K** then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_nb_n \to a_nK \to \pm\infty$ - `Contradiction`

2. if $b_n$ tends to $+\infty$ then by "airithmetic of limits" the multiplication of series will also tend to $+\infty$ also `Contradiction`

3.however, in the case of $b_n \to -\infty$ I got stuck.

Comment: $(+\infty)(-\infty)=-\infty$. But you also need to consider sequences like $0,1,0,1,...$

Comment: let's assume $b_n \not\to 0$, thus either $b_n$ tends to some specific number **K** or it tends to $\pm\infty$ $\rightarrow$ this is a wrong conclusion

Comment: @peter.petrov why? I thought also about b_n that doesn't converge

Comment: @Ami Exactly because of this option.

Answer (score 10):

$b_n=a_nb_n a_n^{-1}\rightarrow 2\times 0=0$

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a proof by contradiction, you can prove it directly.

The limit of $a_nb_n$ is 2, so from a certain index onwards it is between 1 and 3. Without loss of generality we can assume that it is always between 1 and 3 (otherwise cut off equal-length pieces from the front of all three sequences, which does not alter their convergence properties). Similarly assume that all the $a_n$ are positive.

Now $b_n=\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n},$ so $|b_n|\leq\frac3{a_n}$ which must converge to 0 because the numerator is constant and the denominator goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but don't forget about the case where $b_n$ does not converge to number (think $(-1)^n$). What do you know when you assume $b_n\not\to0$? For every $\epsilon$ there are infinitely many terms of $b_n$ that are not within $\epsilon$ of zero. But since $a_n\to\infty$, from some point on all terms are at least $\frac{3}{\epsilon}$, so there are infinitely many terms of $a_nb_n$ that are at least $3$. Contradicting that $a_nb_n\to2$.

Comment: Hi, If you don't mind I would like you to explain better your solution, because I couldn't understand it. :)

Comment: I lost you with your explanation from the point where you say "But since a_n tends to infinity, from some point.....". what all terms and why at least 3/epsilon??

Comment: Sure, convergence of a sequence means that the sequence is eventually within $\epsilon$ of some limit for any positive number $\epsilon$. Divergence to infinity means that the sequence is eventually greater than any positive number $M$. Since $3/\epsilon$ is a positive number, we can apply this definition to the sequence $a_n$.

Comment: Ok, so you choose M= 3/ϵ. but why there are infinitely many terms of $a_nb_n$ that are at least 3? as I understand, $a_nb_n \ge \frac{3}{\epsilon}b_n$ but why $\ge 3$

Comment: Yes, $a_nb_n\geq \frac{3}{\epsilon}b_n$ and since $b_n\geq\epsilon$ infinitely often, $a_nb_n\geq \frac{3}{\epsilon}\epsilon=3$ infinitely often. I chose $3$ because it was the first number bigger than $2$ that I thought of, and showing that $a_nb_n$ is greater than two infinitely often is not sufficient. For $a_nb_n$ to converge to $2$, it must be the case that for every $\epsilon>0$, $a_nb_n$ is eventually within $\epsilon$ of $2$. This is not the case for $\epsilon=1$, so there is the contradiction.

Comment: got you, thanks!